# Ruby on Railsでbulmaが適用されません

Tags: ruby, scss

プログラミングを独学で勉強しておりサンプルでアプリを作っているのですがRuby on Railsでgem bulmaを `bundle install` して `rails s` で画面を開いてもCSSが適用されませんでした。

application.cssもscssに変えて@import bulmaとコードしたのですが以下のようなエラーが出ます。

エラー内容

```
SassC::SyntaxError in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing /Users/hiratashinichi/apple/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma.
        on line 18:2 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>>  @import "bulma";
```

ちなみにappleはrails newのアプリ名のことで、このエラー対策としてbulmaのバージョンを変えて再度bundleをかけたりして@import　bulmaしたりしましたが改善せず、誤字も確かめましたがそれもないのでどうしたら良いか分からないです。
どなたか分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いできませんでしょうか。

Comment: このCSSフレームワークとgemは使ったことありませんが、インストールするgemは bulma ではなく bulma-rails だと思いますが、そちらは合ってますでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: gemfileを確認したらgem "bulma-rails", "~> 0.8.0"でしたので合っていると思うんですが‥

Comment: うーんわからないですね…そもそもの話になりますが、このgemはメンテされていないようですし、使わない方が良いと思いますね